# Multiple message box showing in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am making a one form application and created a hard coded class for my GUI and event handlers.

At first the messagebox is showing once but when I click another button it is showing multiple times, increasing every click of a button.

I have not yet created a unhandled exception is that something to do with that? And if it is unhandled exception how can I do it?

```
private void btnInventoryAddFanbelt_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // CONTENTS
        // labels
        lblFanbeltName.Name = "lblFanbeltName";
        lblFanbeltName.Text = "Fanbelt name";
        lblFanbeltName.Visible = true;
        lblFanbeltName.Location = new Point(10, 10);

        // textbox
        txtFanbeltName.Name = "txtFanbeltName";
        txtFanbeltName.Visible = true;
        txtFanbeltName.Location = new Point(115, 8);

        // buttons
        btnInventorySaveFanbelt.Name = "btnInventorySaveFanbelt";
        btnInventorySaveFanbelt.Text = "Add fanbelt";
        btnInventorySaveFanbelt.Visible = true;
        btnInventorySaveFanbelt.Location = new Point(125, 50);
        // END OF CONTENTS

        // REMOVE CONTROLS
        split3.Panel2.Controls.Clear();

        // ADD CONTROLS
        split3.Panel2.Controls.Add(lblFanbeltName);
        split3.Panel2.Controls.Add(txtFanbeltName);
        split3.Panel2.Controls.Add(btnInventorySaveFanbelt);

        // EVENTHANDLERS
        btnInventorySaveFanbelt.Click += new EventHandler(btnInventorySaveFanbelt_click);

    }

private void btnInventorySaveFanbelt_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        MessageBox.Show("Fanbelt added");

    }
```

Comment: We'll need to see some code if you want help

Comment: Need more information, dawg, provide your button-click-handling code

Comment: Exceptions will crash your program. Most likely you are showing the dialog box with `Show` instead of `ShowDialog`. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to click anything outside the box without closing it first

Comment: @CallumBradbury woof!!

Comment: You are probably assigning the event multiple times.

Comment: and also just new here. how can I post my code. sorry for my noob question

Comment: Click on the edit link under your question.  Four space indent the code.

Comment: Every time you click on `btnInventoryAddFanbelt`, you are adding another click event: `btnInventorySaveFanbelt.Click += new EventHandler(btnInventorySaveFanbelt_click);`  Only add it once, usually best to do that in the constructor or through the designer.  Also, `split3.Panel2.Controls.Clear();` does not dispose of the controls, it just removes them, so you are leaking memory here.  Try using a `while (split3.Panel2.Controls.Count > 0) split3.Panel2.Controls[0].Dispose();`

Comment: thanks mate. it worked like a charm. My gratitude is yours. Now, how can I post this as answered? newbie here sorry for the questions.

Comment: Why are you updating, clearing and re-adding the controls on every click? All of that code would normally appear in the designer's InitializeComponent() method which also ensures it is disposed correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you click on btnInventoryAddFanbelt, you are adding another click event:

```
btnInventorySaveFanbelt.Click += new EventHandler(btnInventorySaveFanbelt_click);
```

Only add it once, usually best to do that in the constructor or through the designer.  It can also be shortened to just:

```
btnInventorySaveFanbelt.Click += btnInventorySaveFanbelt_click;
```

Also, `split3.Panel2.Controls.Clear();` does not dispose of the controls, it just removes them, so you are leaking memory here. Try using:

```
while (split3.Panel2.Controls.Count > 0) {
  split3.Panel2.Controls[0].Dispose();
}
```